How can I keep the proportion of intrinsic width when there is not enough space in a row in Flutter?
I have a row in Flutter like this:
Row(
  children: [
    widgetA,
    widgetB,
    widgetC,
  ]
);

The row may not have enough space to contain all the widgets in their intrinsic widths. In this case, how can I keep the proportion of their intrinsic widths when putting these widgets in the row when they are constrained in width?

not sure if you are looking for Wrap

Did you try Flexible ?
